# get all recently viewed product id

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to get all recently viewed product's id programmatically . I tried to check the reports/product_viewed and reports/product_abstract. But couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

> $collection = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed')->getItemsCollection();

Comment: can we add customer id filter with this ??? for getting specific customer recently viewed products

Answer (score 0):

If you like to get only the IDs and don't want extra logic from the block, you can try to use directly this:

```
$ids = Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_viewed')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
```